# Is it still necessary to support plain-text emails?

Tags: email, mime

We're creating a web application that sends emails for different purposes.  Since we need to embed images and links in some of the messages, HTML is a must.

Most of the email messages can be customized by our users. We provide a web-based editor to do that. Requiring our users to enter always two message variants, one in HTML, one in plain text, is no option, that's just annoying for the users, so our current approach is to specify a plain-text part with something like "please use an HTML-capable mail client".

**Is this a valid approach, or do I break certain clients that could still be relevant?** I know that this question depends on our user base, but I'd like to get a general suggestion for "most cases" in the year 2015.

If this is not an option, are there any sensible ways to automatically construct a plain-text message out of the HTML message?

Answer (score 0):

IMO it's a valid approach. I can't think of any commonly-used mail clients that are still plain-text only. Can you?